# How can I satisfy both network and privilege in a container?

Tags: docker, networking, containers, privileges, dbus

My host's kernel version, OS version and docker version

```
root@lfgphispre02441:/etc# uname -a
Linux lfgphispre02441 4.15.0-154-generic #161-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 30 13:04:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@lfgphispre02441:/etc# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

root@lfgphispre02441:/etc# docker version
Client:
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.8
 Git commit:        20.10.7-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
 Built:             Wed Aug  4 22:43:25 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.8
  Git commit:       20.10.7-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
  Built:            Wed Aug  4 19:22:59 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.5.2-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  GitCommit:
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0~rc95-0ubuntu1~18.04.2
  GitCommit:
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:
```

I use root user. My image is based on ubuntu 20.04.

When I run a container on a server with the following command

```
docker run -d --name $MYNAME --privileged $IMAGE /usr/sbin/init
```

Use the default bridge mode.
then

```
docker exec -it $MYNAME /bin/bash
```

I want to install some packages like

```
apt install uml-utilities
```

A network error has occurred

On the host , i inspect the container's IP

```
172.17.0.32
```

But inside the container

```
root@6677433e782c:/# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
70: eth0@if71: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:20 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:20/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

There is no IPv4 IP address, only IPv6 IP address, and no network.

I did the same thing on another server(OS: ubuntu 20.04) and occasionally had the same problem, but generally no problems.
After the container is restarted, the network recovers, but I need --privileged to run the container. After the container is restarted, the dbus cannot be accessed.

Comment: Please add your kernel version, OS version and docker version to the post. Provide `uname -a`, `cat /etc/os-relese` and `docker version` output.

Comment: That doesn't sound like you want to run a Docker container at all.  If you want the host network, a privileged container, and access to the host's systemd, just run the process using `sudo`.

Comment: I've added my kernel version, OS version and docker version，and i use root user.